# GWT Inheritance

Tags: gwt, inheritance

How is inheritance handled in GWT? 
If I have 3 modules A -> B -> C and I declare that B inherits from A, and C inherits from B, supposing that C uses A, do I have to explicitly declare that C inherits also from A or it is enough with the former declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModuleXml :

> <inherits name="logical-module-name" /> : Inherits all the settings from the specified
>   module as if the contents of the inherited module's XML were copied verbatim.

This means C will automatically inherit from A. You do however have to make sure C has the sources of A available on the GWT compile path (but that's the same for B).